# php syntax checker that understands indentation

Tags: php, syntax, editor, lint

Consider this php script:

```
<?php                       // 1
                            // 2
function foo() {            // 3
                            // 4
    $foo = 1;               // 5
                            // 6
    if("something") {       // 7
        $bar = 2;           // 8
                            // 9 = note the missing brace
                            // 10
    $baz = 4;               // 11
                            // 12
}                           // 13
?>                          // 14
```

When you run it, you'll get the parse error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... on line 14
```

Is there a tool for php that would be smart enough to analyze my indentation and to tell me that the actual problem is on line 9 (or 11, for that matter), not at the end of the script.

Comment: Unlikely, because indentation has no actual meaning in PHP.... it's an aid for human readability, not machine readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP_CodeSniffer is marginally helpful here. This is what it prints for the script in question:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 4 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | ERROR | Missing file doc comment
  3 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
  8 | ERROR | Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4
 22 | ERROR | Closing brace indented incorrectly; expected 4 spaces, found 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The 3rd message  is confusing, still it's closer to the source of the problem than the default one.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is pretty much unsolvable. A compiler will do its best to tell you where an error occurred, but it can't do it infallibly. Essentially it will keep scanning the file until it reaches something that must be invalid at that point; but that doesn't mean that's where you screwed up. It just means that at the point you made your mistake, what followed was still technically valid syntax (even if totally silly) until the point where the compiler gave up in disgust.

So in your case, the syntax is technically fine until line 14, even though the code deviated from what you intended in line 9. The parser can't know that.

Since indentation is optional and ignored by the parser, it would almost certainly cause more trouble than it was worth for it to take the indentation into account. If it did, it would keep coming up with errors where there weren't errors. After all, one consequence of indentation's not being syntactically meaningful is that there is more than one reasonable way to do indentation.

Your best bet, I think, would be to use an IDE that automatically *adds* the indentation for you. (Eclipse certainly can be configured to sort out indentation for you.) If you do that, you'll discover as you write line 11 that it wants to indent it more than you were expecting, and that'll give you a clue that you forgot a closing brace.

Comment: There's nothing "unsolvable" about it. The algorithm to detect this kind of errors is actually very simple (see Philipp's post).

Comment: Well, perhaps I should have said that it's unrealistic to solve it satisfactorily. There is no unique "correct" indentation policy in PHP, so you'd end up with spurious errors and warnings unless it was coded to work precisely with your indentation policy. And I have my suspicions that no one is entirely consistent with their own indentation policy in any case! This is why I think it's better to have something that enforces the indentation as you write: it'll pick up on these things much earlier.

Comment: I'm pretty confident my indentation is correct ;)... but still, a good point, thanks. Perhaps I can use "Reformat code" in Idea and look where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this would be possbile and not that hard to implement as an plugin for some IDE's(Netbeans, PHP Storm, Eclipse, ...)
But I don't know any plugin or IDE which offers currently such an functionallity. Maybe you can implement it on your own.

The easy implementation would  be something like

- split your code into lines
- determine the indention for each line
- on indention level change look for `{`
- case 1 no `{`
- - => if there are multiple identions of level n+1 in the next lines - throw an warning
- case 2: `{`
- - go forward till the next idention level change and look for `}`
- - if theres no `}` => throw an warning

this procedure should be called recursive

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't technically answer the question but I find that the syntax highlighting in netbeans *helps* no end with this problem.

I couldn't live without it now.

[image]